# Is there a limit in PHP to the length of a variable name or function name?

Tags: php, variables, syntax

If I wanted to write a really long variable name like:

```
$this_is_my_variable_that_does_something_in_the_following_function_and_provides_some_information_with_which_the_function_relies_upon_to_do_all_the_work_it_needs = null;
```

would that work? same question for function/method names

Comment: You should make that camel case, otherwise it is hard to read.

Comment: @PMV: `$thisIsMyVariableThatDoesSomethingInTheFollowingFunctionAndProvidesSomeInformationWith WhichTheFunctionReliesUponToDoAllTheWorkItNeeds = null;` Yeah, that looks easy to read. I can say it in a single breath! **\*inhales\***

Comment: @BoltClock: Probably capitalize NULL too, since it's a constant.  Then it would be a perfectly readable and sensible statement.  Too bad punctuation isn't allowed though.

Comment: @PMV: Yeah I forgot that. I always capitalize it in my code.

Comment: A good question, but trivial to answer for yourself.  Did you try it?

Comment: As PHP doesn't define any limit. I do prefer ANSI standards, it recognizes a length of 31 characters for a variable name. However, the length should not be normally more than any combination of eight alphabets, digits, and underscores.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Generally, such a limit is imposed by the threat of violence from other folks who interact with your code.

Comment: I just had a good laugh reading your explanation. The exact same thing often happens if your code only uses only single-letter variables like `$i`, `$n` or `$k`.

Comment: So,  
`if (strlen($varname) < 4 || strlen($varname) > 16) { SKINNERRRRRR(!!!!!1); }`

Comment: @RobinJ By choice of the posting user, like every other accepted answer on the site. It's also, IMO, a perfectly accurate answer - technological limitations aren't the only ones. Also, it's five years old... why ask now?

Comment: @Jocelyn Is single-letter variable bad also for iterators, e.g. `for` and `while`?

Answer (score 99):

From the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variable names follow the same rules
>   as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or
>   underscore, followed by **any number**
>   of letters, numbers, or underscores

The same is the case for function names, as stated [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

Comment: So writing 200 underscores on a line (and a semicolon at the end) is perfectly valid as long as notices are switched off! Time to introduce my new separators :)

Comment: I would prefer the ANSI recommendation for the safer side given for C after all PHP is written in c (a length of mo more than 31 characters for a variable name.)

Answer (score 18):

The limit in variable/function/method/class name length does not exist.

Comments above states that that this property should not be exploited. That is true only when it comes to human readable/human maintainable code.

However, this is extremely useful feature of PHP, that is exploited very well in a lot of very popular projects, such as Twig per example, which generates classes, example (a snippet):

```
class __TwigTemplate_9601167421099bbb502d119e674fed3fb71769eef256903648c9c2b4b6faa436 extends \Twig_Template {

    protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array())
    {
        $__internal_0abebc74dd811fd7b4cfa4c6a2fdf870d7723c04e8daf6926b04914d6644935f = $this->env->getExtension("native_profiler");    
    }

}
```

I had opportunity to benefit from same property as well in my projects.

## In conclusion:

- There is no limit in var/func/class name length
- It is extremely useful language feature
- There is a context for its usage, of course, it is not for every day work

Comment: Sure about this "There is no limit in var/func/class name length"? Do you have any reference ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no limit - but it is highly not suggested as it creates unreadable code...

Comment: All the opposite, it does create very readable code indeed. It's much more expressive `$arrivalDateTimeWithUnknownTimeZoneAndIncorrectlyAssignedUtcTimeZone` (real example from our production code) than just `$arrivalDateTime`. Reason: In the second one the human reading your code will have to ask you if there's a bug or not because it has an Utc time zone while in reality the time zone was actually unknown. In the first case it's clear it was on purpose.

Comment: It makes very unreadable code and makes the code harder to type. There's a reason why comments exist, don't put all the information in the variable name.

Comment: On the other hand, comments are harder to maintain. When you have the reason for a variable on it's own name, it makes life easier. It actually takes less time to read a long variable, than always having to go to the definition and reading a comment.

Comment: Big variable/function/etc names run the risk of misspelling; forget a double-r or a capital-Z on `$arrivalDateTimeWithUnknownTimeZoneAndIncorrectlyAssignedUtcTimeZone` and try to find the error on a heavy coding day. If you need to travel such a variable across hundreds of lines of code I would suggest describing it by code, like: `$arrivalDateTime = array("timestamp" => 3213546, "timeZone" => false, "assignedUTC" => false);`

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not pose a length limit on it's identifiers.

That said, I'm not sure why anybody would ever want to create a 160 character variable name.  I hope this is a hypothetical question.

Comment: Well I was thinking of writing of framework/coding standard that didn't use comments and instead relied on using really descriptive variable and function names =P

Comment: You should name it Framework/CodingStandardThatDoesn'tUseCommentsandInsteadReliesonUsingReallyDescriptiveVariableandFunctionNamesCMS.

Comment: Ugh. So you expect a long variable name to substitute for a comment that explains why someone did something bizarre? Good luck with that.

Comment: Maybe it's just dynamic stuff identifiers ;)

Comment: There is a usage context - auto generated vars/classes/functions

Comment: Not 160, but this is real production code for me: `$arrivalDateTimeWithUnknownTimeZoneAndIncorrectlyAssignedUtcTimeZone`. +1 for @ceejayoz and clean code rulez!

Answer (score -3):

PHP doesn't have any restriction for variable name. And my suggestion is that variable name must consist the definition of the data which you are gonna store into it.

Comment: You answered a question almost 9 years later, with adding no new points. Please consider answering an old question only if you can provide a different solution/answer.